# application view/component in ember-cli 2.13

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have recently started a new project with the most recent ember-cli (v 2.13 as stated in the topic). I am rather set on generating clean semantic html, and as such don't like the extra div.ember-view that the application generates.

Before I could create the app/views/application.js file with following content:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: ''
});
```

It simply used the component as application view and got rid of the root tag, however it doesn't seem to work anymore. In fact when debugging the resolver "view:application" doesn't show up at all. Is there a new way of solving this situation? Afaik routable components are not exactly in yet, are they?

Granted, my last ember project was using ember-rails (with ember 2.7), now I'm going for a pure ember-cli project, so a few things might indeed have changed.

How can the same effect be achieved now? Is it just a case of adding a special rule to resolver? Or maybe it can be reached otherwise? I learned that ember docs can be rather lacking when it comes to new obscure features...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Views` are removed from the Ember 2.0 API. Have a look at this deprecation https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view.

Regarding your question, you can find related discussions in the below url.
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11486

Implementing `tagName: ''` is not suggested one. **In current situation, you can't remove that extra div created by ember application**, since ember needs that. What you can do is, you can just apply CSS style to mitigate this,

```
:root,
.ember-application,
.ember-application>div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not the styling that I have a problem with, but the very idea of semantic html and minimising the amount of unnecessary tags.
Thanks for the links, though.

Comment: Acutally this extra div will be created only for application route, and unfortunately it can't be removed in ember

Comment: Okay, in that case, might be by any chance possible to still access the application component to just change the tag used, not remove it? I'd just like to do tagName: 'section', or something similar, but for the main application, not a sub component? The trick above with substituting a component in app/views/ doesn't seem to work anymore...

Comment: changing application wrapper to `section` instead of `div` also not possible..I am not sure my assumption is correct or not. so you please discuss with ember community people in slack to confirm it https://embercommunity.slack.com

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an account on embercommunity.slack.com, and from what I understand, I'd need to be invited.

Comment: click this link you will be invited to join - https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Views are deprecated in Ember > 2.0. The components do generate a div with div.ember-view class added. You can give custom classes to that component using the **classNames** property and for the component to be other than a div, specify the element to the **tagName** property.

The extra div can be eliminated using **tagName: " "** inside each component but you cannot use this.$() to access the component element. The only option is to customize the div created according to our needs.

For application template, I don't think there is any hack to eliminate the extra div created. It might be required by the eventDispatcher.

Comment: Still, the code I included in my original question did work as expected in 2.7 - was that functionality removed completely between 2.7 and 2.13? Or does the resolver provided with ember-cli work differently than the one in ember-rails?

Comment: It doesn't work in ember-cli 2.7 version either. The resolvers are different for both.